# How to capture video with an external camera using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I'm trying to capture a video from my pixy2 camera.
I wrote this code:

```
import cv2 as cv

vid = cv.VideoCapture(1, cv.CAP_DSHOW)

while (True):

    ret, frame = vid.read()

    cv.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

vid.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
"C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\OpenCV tutorial\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/OpenCV tutorial/OpenCV_1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\OpenCV tutorial\OpenCV_1.py", line 14, in <module>
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help, please!!

Comment: Hello @Hussein Jammal :) welcome to stackoverlow :) This is an external camera? Are you doing this test on a laptop that has a built-in camera as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually this error doesn't base on your videocapture operation. -As properly u set the capture parameter as 1 -

Here are two tips that will you help to determine the reason behind this error;

1. First use this line right after `vid = cv.VideoCapture(1, cv.CAP_DSHOW)` this line on your code:

`vid not cap.isOpened(): print("Cannot open camera") exit()` 
This code helps you to understand whether your external camera is on or off.

2. The second tip is about the reading stage.

`if not ret: print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...") break`

You will get the error at 1.st step or 2.nd step then, yes!

By the way Welcome :)